# Making an new ArrayList<String> from ArrayList<UserBean> of an bean class

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of an bean class consisting five fields as

Java Bean -- MyShares

1. fileName
2. filePath
3. fileSize
4. isShared
5. Creator

I Want to make a ArrayList of filePath from this arraylist of bean class

I don't have vast knowledge on Java collections. So what will be the shortest logic for this.

The present logic which I have implemented is below, **Now I want an optimized Logic to do so**

```
ArrayList<Myshares> fileDetails = new ReadSDCard().getSdCardFiles();

        if (!fileDetails.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < fileDetails.size(); i++) {
                CommonUtilities.filePaths.add(fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
            }
        }

        if (!CommonUtilities.filePaths.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < CommonUtilities.filePaths.size(); i++) {

                Log.d(Integer.toString(i), CommonUtilities.filePaths.get(i));
            }
        }
```

CommonUtilities.filePaths is my static ArrayList in which I want to store the file paths

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use for-each (`for (Myshares share : fileDetails)`) instead of the index based iteration. Then you don't need to check if the list is empty.

Comment: @user714965 is there any difference in speed pf execution in using for each and indexed for

Comment: Don't know, maybe.. try it. The logic will be optimized though (regarding readability).

Comment: @user714965 I am trying waitb 1 min

Comment: @user714965 No there is no difference in speed of execution. I have tried a code both have takem 0.7 sec to execute see By for loop with index http://ideone.com/bwqH0V and with for each http://ideone.com/cpmG6x

Comment: Your first script uses an array. Your question a list. You can't compare this. Also you have to run your script maybe 10000 times to see a difference. Anyway, the best optimization (regarding performance) is to use only one loop.

Comment: But if we considering for looping execution time then it is same for these values. Also the memory consumed is also the same. Definately what are you saying is correct

Comment: @Nikhil I don't think so. The `get` is something the indexed loop have to do and the foreach doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im struggeling to understand why you would have two loops. One that loops through the `fileDetails` collection and add the paths to a new collection, and then you loop through the new collection for logging. Do these two steps in the same loop:

```
    if (!fileDetails.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < fileDetails.size(); i++) {
            CommonUtilities.filePaths.add(fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
            Log.d(Integer.toString(i), fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
        }
    }
```

Other then that I cannot see how this could be optimated since it's impossible to add the paths to a new array without looping through the one with fileDetails. This logic will run in O(n) time

Comment: You should cache `fileDetails.get(i).getPath()` in a local variable to avoid calling it twice.

Comment: @John Snow I have used two for loops for some purpose. I have to write some code over there. By any method Can't we extract that one field value means the file path in single line of code without for loop

Comment: Well, that kind of fine tuning is not really worth it. A call to a getter would be no different in having the garbage collector handeling the extra local variable. It also requires one more lines of code for no perfomance gain

Comment: @Nikhil - If you want to access a known index, sure that could be done. But if you want to add a path for each object in your collection you have to loop through it

Comment: Actually I would spend two lines of code. One for `Object detail = fileDetails.get(i)` and one for `String path = detail.getPath()`. This makes it easier to find null pointers from the log file for example and makes it easier to maintain also. Trust me there are enough free lines available you don't have to spare them.

Answer (score 1):

What you doing is fine but u need to check whether path is `null` before inserting in `CommonUtilities.filePaths`. You can also use a iterator instead of for loop.

You can may be avoid two for loops and just do the following:

```
ArrayList<Myshares> fileDetails = new ReadSDCard().getSdCardFiles();
       int j=0;

        if (!fileDetails.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileDetails.size(); i++) {
              if(fileDetails.get(i).getPath()!=null){
                CommonUtilities.filePaths.add(fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
                Log.d(Integer.toString(j), CommonUtilities.filePaths.get(j));
                j++;
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Nikhil i just suggested checking null because would you really want to add a null because  'CommonUtilities.filePaths' will contain null values and if your trying to use the elements of this list elsewhere you will get NullPointerException so it is better to check if the data is null before insertion as ArrayList can contain null values. Plus 'Log.d(Integer.toString(j), CommonUtilities.filePaths.get(j));' will log null values if you are not checking for null.

Comment: Y that is true But for that purpose I have created a check null function which detects for data type and then check for null and if null assign a genuine value to that. And here I have asked my problem and someone has down-voted me. People has to specify reasons why they are downvoting

Comment: @Nikhil good if you are checking for null i just gave an answer to your question on how this code can be improved from what i can see here there was no function to check null, plus i had also suggested the use of single loop and i didn't down vote you.

Comment: No I am not saying you have down voted me just I am discussing the issue with you. And thanks for the suggestion. Can I have your contact details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28078/discussion-between-nikhil-and-lakshmi)

Answer (score 0):

Why to use CommonUtilities again to get the file paths ? We can log the path at the same instance while iterating

```
 ArrayList<Myshares> fileDetails = new ReadSDCard().getSdCardFiles();

            if (!fileDetails.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0,n=fileDetails.size(); i < n; i++) {

                    CommonUtilities.filePaths.add(fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
                Log.d(Integer.toString(i),fileDetails.get(i).getPath());
                }
            }
```

Please see the construct :

```
  for (int i = 0,n=fileDetails.size(); i < n; i++)
```

We can use this , provided , we are sure that fileDetails.size() will return same result (list is not being modified).
This will save us from calling fileDetails.size() each time